# Hid parts of user control based on data source in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `user control` which contains 2 shapes, an ellipse and rectangle. What I want to do is hide the rectangle if the data source I'm binding to is set to false, and visible if true. The same for the ellipse.

So in my case how can I set the visibility of the ellipse based on the ismale bool. Also set the rectangle visibility based on isFemale bool?

**User Control**

```
<UserControl> 
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    MinWidth="200" MinHeight="120">
      <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Margin="5" />
      <Ellipse Fill="Red" Margin="5" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Pseudo code for class object I'm data binding to in my mvvm setup.

```
class Person
{
    public bool IsMale {get;set;}
    public bool IsFemale {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `DataTrigger` for each `Style` of the shape.

```
<UserControl> 
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          MinWidth="200" 
          MinHeight="120">
      <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Margin="5">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collpased"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFemale}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
      </Rectangle>
      <Ellipse Fill="Red" Margin="5">
        <Ellipse.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collpased"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMale}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Ellipse.Style>
      </Ellipse>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Also, note that the DataContext of the `UserControl` must of of type `Person` object.

Comment: Here is another related question. Say for example i have 5 different 'Path' data. How can i display a specific path based on a value?